Could not add identity communication with agent failed with -t option on Windows
I tried the following command to add a key on Windows.
ssh-add -t 1d "\path\to\mysshkey"

Which returns

Could not add identity communication with agent failed

The agent seems to work well.
Doing the same command without the -t option works perfectly
ssh-add "\path\to\mysshkey"

Question would be, why is the error message so bad (seems that it should say -t option is not supported)?
